# Replace xml subnode value in AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I'm trying to update a value in a subnode of an XML structure. New value should come from an Input TextField whose instance name is the same of the value of the attribute of the node I should update.

For example, when focusing out textfield called "label10", I should edit the node:

```
<label id="label10">
    <eng>Description</eng>
    <de>DE Description</de>
</label>
```

...and that's ok, I achieved it using this callback function:

```
private function onFocusOut (evt:FocusEvent):void {
        var nodeToModify:XML = xmlFillData.label.(@id==evt.target.name)[0];
        trace ("nodeToModify is " +nodeToModify );
}
```

Now my problem is I wish to replace the content of the subnode eng or de, depending on a variable defined in a static class called VarHolder, but I'm not able to do it.

I've tried to use this line inside the callback function:

```
 nodeToModify.replace (VarHolder.activeLang , evt.target.text);
```

but then if I trace nodeToModify, this is the result ( tag disappeared)

```
<label id="label10">
rrr
<de>DE Description</de>
```

Any help?

---

EDIT (and solved): trying to implement @jens answer.
This is how I did it

```
 nodeToModify.replace (VarHolder.activeLang,  new XML("<" + VarHolder.activeLang + ">" +  evt.target.text + "</" + VarHolder.activeLang + ">"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XML.replace()` does expect the 2nd parameter to be an XML-Object which then is converted to a (XML-)string. Meaning: it replaces '`<eng>Description</eng>`' with '`rrr`' and its working as intended. You need to pass it an XML-object or pass it '`<eng>rrr</eng>`'. If the value of `VarHolder.activeLang` is plainly 'eng', you could use this:

```
nodeToModify.replace (VarHolder.activeLang ,  "<" + VarHolder.activeLang + ">" + 
                           evt.target.text + "</" + VarHolder.activeLang + ">");
```

See this link for more information on XML.replace():
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#replace%28%29

Comment: thx @jens, I tried this solution before posting the question, I was hoping there was another solution to do it. By the way, I gave up with that because when tracing it I was reading: &lt;eng&gt;rrr&lt;/eng&gt;  any idea of how to get rid of that?