# AS3: How to replace XMLList?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I want to replace `XMLList` of some `XML`.

I been trying to do this:

```
public function update(parameters:XMLList):void {
    xml.replace("parameters", parameters);
    var item:* = xml.parameters[0];
    trace(item, parameters[0]);
}
```

But its not working, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Second parameter requires `XML` object and not `XMLList`.

See [XML Replace](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#replace%28%29)

See also [Replace XML Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228756/replace-xml-subnode-value-in-as3)

Giving some idea though. May need to improve second parameter.

`xml.replace("parameters", new XML("<" + parameters + "/>"));`